# "SubTypes" with own Show and usable in other Module

Tags: haskell, types

I am pretty sure my problem stems from the fact that I am new to Haskell and do not understand the type system completely.

I will use the example used in Haskell's wiki on the type topic

The following Type is defined

```
 data Suit = Club | Diamond | Heart | Spade
```

Now the first issue is, I would like to implement `Show` for every "sub-type" (Club, Diamond, Heart, Spade) but this doesn't seem to work because it is a `DataKinds`. So I split it up into their own types. (The properties don't make much sense but I added them to be closer to the real code)

```
data ClubType = ClubType {
  clubName :: String,
  icon :: String
} 
instance Show ClubType where
  show (ClubType cn i) = "name: " ++ cn ++ ", icon: " ++ i
```

Using them in the Suit type

```
data Suit = Club ClubType 
          | Diamond DiamondType 
          | Heart HeartType 
          | Spade SpadeType
```

Now I want to use Suit and the "Sub-Types" (Club, Diamond, Heart, Spade) in a different `module`. I exported just `Suit (..)`.

**Usage**

```
import Module1 (Suit(..))

getSuit :: String -> Suit
getSuit "Club" = getClub
getSuit "Heart" = getHeart
...

getClub :: () -> Club
```

Now again `Club`, `Heart`, `Diamond` and `Spade` cannot be used because they are `DataKinds`. How do I use the "sub-types"? Do I need to export all types? If I do, does it conform with the return type of `getSuit`?

(Sorry if the example doesn't make a whole lot of sense, but I hope you can follow my desired result)

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it sounds like you don't really understand the type system.  I will try my best to clarify where I think you are going wrong.  In your example

```
data Suit = Club | Diamond | Heart | Spade
```

There is only one type, and that is `Suit`.  `Club`, `Diamond`, etc. are not types at all, and you will confuse yourself if you refer to them as "sub-types".  The proper name for them is *constructors*, and they are essentially values of type `Suit`

```
Club :: Suit
Diamond :: Suit
...
```

So you can't really implement a `Show` instance for "each one", you can only implement a `Show` instance for the whole type `Suit`, in the usual way, by pattern matching on the constructors:

```
instance Show Suit where
    show Club = "Clubs"
    show Diamond = "Diamonds"
    show Heart = "Heart"
    show Spade = "Spade"
```

This defines a single function `show` on the type `Suit -> String`, again there is no "sub-type" anything going on.  I wonder if this was all you were looking for.

Since you mention datakinds, using the constructors at the type level still does not make them types -- they are still values of type `Suit`.  An example of using them at the type level is to index a GADT by these:

```
data Card :: Suit -> * where
    QueenOfSpades :: Card Spade
    OtherCard :: Int -> Card s   -- we'd want to encode the suit s at the data
                                 -- level too using a singleton, out of scope
                                 -- for this post
```

But this is fairly advanced stuff and probably not what you are looking for.

I hope this clarifies things a little.

Comment: I was about to ask about why the answer was so short. :) Holding my horses!

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Can I reference the *constructors* in any way? Is it possible to define a function that returns a `Club` or should I just use `Suit` everywhere?

Comment: You can't talk about the constructors at the type level (except as I showed in the GADT example, but I wouldn't worry about that until you're quite a bit more experienced), just use `Suit`.

Comment: A function can return a `Club` in the same way a function can return the number 3 or the string `"foo"`: for example, `f :: Int -> Suit; f 0 = Club; f 1 = Diamond; f 2 = Heart; f 3 = Spade`. In a very real sense, defining a new type adds new literals to the language. `Suit` isn't just a set of integer-valued variables; it is an entire distinct type with its own constants.

Comment: Closest thing in imperative languageso is an enum.